# Swift resizable image on scrolling content

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview, resize

I'm trying to replicate the behavior of [this repository](https://github.com/vicentesuarez/Swift-FlexibleHeightBar) but simplified, as Xcode is giving me errors when importing the code (which is pretty old and when I tried to upgrade it from Swift 3 to 5 it just didn't work due to Xcode showing errors (I just deleted the files and it's fine again, so I don't have the errors it was showing).

So, what I'm trying to do is to reduce the height and apply a background color when the height is lower than 50% of the original size.

What I'm first trying to do, is be able to resize the image and increase the height of the `ScrollView` as the user scrolls.

For this, I created a simple storyboard:

[image]

And I thought that maybe using the `willBeginDragging` method from the scrollView's delegate I could reduce the height of the imageView, but it looks like it's not as straight forward as I thought it would be...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UIScrollView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        resizeImageView()
        scrollView.delegate = self
    }

    func resizeImageView() {
        
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageView.frame.width, height: 50)
    }
}
```

How could I achieve the same effect as in this image?

[image]

Comment: Take a search for `uiscrollview parallax header swift` ... you may find something already suitable for your use. If not, you can likely find something close, and then edit it to fit your needs.

Comment: Thank you @DonMag this actually helped